# Save Spark 2.3.0 dataset as image format

Tags: apache-spark, image-processing

Using Spark 2.3.0 new feature, ImageSchema, I've read some images as dataset, and now after applying changes on them, I want to save them as image formats (png, jpeg).
I got each dataset row's data (byte[]) and tried to save it as `png` file, but the exported file is not valid!

```
Dataset<Row> images = ImageSchema.readImages("images/");
images.foreach(data_row -> {
    Row row = data_row.getAs(0);
    File file = new File(Paths.get(ImageSchema.getOrigin(row)).getFileName().toString() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    fos.write(ImageSchema.getData(row));
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```